# Spark writing output as fixed width

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, fixed-width

Reading a fixed-width file into Spark is easy and there are multiple ways to do so. However, I could not find a way to WRITE fixed-width output from spark (2.3.1). Would converting a DF to RDD help? Currently using Pyspark but any language is welcome. Can someone suggest a way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of what I described in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549762/spark-writing-output-as-fixed-width?noredirect=1#comment93990640_53549762).

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.format_string()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.format_string) to format each column to a fixed width and then use [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) to combine them all into one string.

For example, suppose you had the following DataFrame:

```python
data = [
    (1, "one", "2016-01-01"),
    (2, "two", "2016-02-01"),
    (3, "three", "2016-03-01")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "value", "date"])
df.show()
#+---+-----+----------+
#| id|value|      date|
#+---+-----+----------+
#|  1|  one|2016-01-01|
#|  2|  two|2016-02-01|
#|  3|three|2016-03-01|
#+---+-----+----------+
```

Let's say you wanted to write out the data left-justified with a fixed width of 10

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, format_string

fixed_width = 10
ljust = r"%-{width}s".format(width=fixed_width)

df.select(
    concat(*[format_string(ljust,c) for c in df.columns]).alias("fixedWidth")
).show(truncate=False)
#+------------------------------+
#|fixedWidth                    |
#+------------------------------+
#|1         one       2016-01-01|
#|2         two       2016-02-01|
#|3         three     2016-03-01|
#+------------------------------+
```

Here we use the `printf` style formatting of `%-10s` to specify a left justified width of 10.

If instead you wanted to right-justify your strings, remove the negative sign:

```python
rjust = r"%{width}s".format(width=fixed_width)

df.select(
    concat(*[format_string(rjust,c) for c in df.columns]).alias("fixedWidth")
).show(truncate=False)
#+------------------------------+
#|fixedWidth                    |
#+------------------------------+
#|         1       one2016-01-01|
#|         2       two2016-02-01|
#|         3     three2016-03-01|
#+------------------------------+
```

Now you can write out only the `fixedWidth` column to your output file.

Comment: 1.What would happen if number of columns are large and the total length of concatenated string is too large? Any problem with maximum length of characters stored in a single column?

Comment: @SreenathChothar why don't you try it and see what happens? If you run into trouble, you can post a new question.

Comment: How to format a date column? Tried with code after converting the string column 'date' to date type column 'date1': df.withColumn('new',format_string('%tc','date1')). But it is failing with illegalformatconversionexception. We have a large number of date type columns in the dataframe that needs to be outputted as fixed width file.

Comment: @SreenathChothar please post a new question and provide a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).